# Decrypt a href link that hidden using javascript:void(0)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am developing a simple PHP script to grab the real link from a website while the real link/key is hidden using `javascript:void(0)` method
I tried to analyze the view source code but it shows the herf link empty and replaced with # sign

but when I show the code using inspect elements it appears correctly as following

```
<td valign="middle" align="left">
    <span class="post_version_link">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="embed-link popper" link_version="1" open-text="Close" close-text="Version 3" key="2Q6tiz7">Version 3</a>
      (<a href="/links/go/2Q6tiz7" class="propper-link popper" link_version="1" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" onclick="trackOutboundLink('example.com');" key="2Q6tiz7">Direct</a>)
    </span>
</td>
```

In view source or PHP grab, the code appears as following

```
<td align="left" valign="middle">
<span class="post_version_link">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="embed-link popper" link_version="1" open-text="Close" close-text="Version 3">Version 3</a>
  (<a href="#" class="propper-link popper" link_version="1" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" onclick="trackOutboundLink('example.com');">Direct</a>)
</span>
</td>
```

**Update1:** There is an event listener Javascript on that herf link

```
function(t) {
  return "undefined" != typeof ke && ke.event.triggered !== t.type ? ke.event.dispatch.apply(e, arguments) : void 0
}
```

Comment: The source is likely altered after the page loads via Javascript.

Comment: Yes, there is an event listener Javascript on that herf link. Updated my question to add that javascript

Comment: That's my point. Viewing the source code of the page shows the source before any Javascript executes. That href is changed in JS, so you can't get the link this way. You have to either crawl the Javascript and simulate what it does, or open the link in a DOM (like an iframe) and wait for the JS to execute.

Answer (score -1):

You can leave the `href` as blank or as `#`. You can then redirect the click to a specific URL. Example:

```js
$(function() {
  function go(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location.href = "/links/go/" + $(e.target).attr("key");
  }

  $(".embed-link").click(go);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td valign="middle" align="left">
  <span class="post_version_link">
      <a href="#" class="embed-link popper" link_version="1" open-text="Close" close-text="Version 3" key="2Q6tiz7">Version 3</a>
    </span>
</td>
```